# Signalling when an updated PHP dynamic clock has received new input

Tags: javascript, php

i've built a basic countdown timer in PHP which will echo the result back to be displayed on page by javascript every second (or every minute, I havent decided if doing a get call every second will cause any issues yet)

So the countdown works by taking input from a user and updating a DB serverside. PHP then takes this value, converts it into a time format and uses it to calculate the end time for the countdown.

My question is, I would like the timer to flash or something similar when the time changes based on new DB input... So for example the timer would be counting down to 2 hours. Another user submits the form which updates the database so now the end time is 5 hours away. Id like to somehow capture this change so I can display a message on the page.

I'm wracking my brains about how to do this but cannot think of a method.

**basic PHP im using to calculate the end time**

```
    <?php

    $timeUntil = 100; // placeholder, actual variable will be integer pulled from db
    $unixTime = 86400;
    $zTime = $timeUntil * $unixTime;
    $endDate = time() + zTime;
    $remaining = $endDate - time();
    $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
    $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
    $minutes_remaining = floor((($remaining % 86400) % 3600) / 60);
    $seconds_remaining = floor((($remaining % 86400) % 3600) % 60);
    $zTimeCombined = array($days_remaining, $hours_remaining,     
    $minutes_remaining, $seconds_remaining);
    echo $zTimeCombined;
    ?>
```

Comment: Why not just update the DB? When a client request how much time is left respond with a timstamp. If the client's time stamp does not match the server timestamp, do that flash thing.

Comment: so on the initial get request include the current user time, within PHP compare this value to the value it generates from the DB and send another string back (true or false etc) as part of the array to JS to evaluate? Thats a pretty good idea actually, think ill try that. Want to stick it on an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally use websockets for this. Doing too many AJAX requests is the best way to kill your server. What you need for this is [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) on the PHP-side and WebSockets (no lib needed) on the JS-side.

On the server, onOpen, you would send the current timer time and you would send a new message to every client if the time is updated.

Here is a small example:

composer.json:

```
{
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.3.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "App/"
        }
    }
}
```

socket.php:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Chat;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;

$var = new Chat;
$var = new WsServer($var);
$var = new HttpServer($var);
$var = IoServer::factory($var, 8080);
$var->run();
```

App/Chat.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use SplObjectStorage;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface as Connection;
use Exception;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    public $clients;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->clients = new SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public function onOpen(Connection $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
    }

    public function onMessage(Connection $from, $msg)
    {
        foreach ($this->clients as $key => $value) {
            if ($value != $from) {
                $value->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(Connection $conn)
    {
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
    }

    public function onError(Connection $conn, Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    <input type="text" id="input">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">


    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')

        socket.onmessage = function (msg) {
            addToChat(msg.data)
        }

        var input  = document.getElementById('input')
        var submit = document.getElementById('submit')

        submit.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()

            if (input.value.length > 0) {
                addToChat(input.value)
                socket.send(input.value)
                input.value = ''
            }
        })

        function addToChat(msg) {
            document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p>'
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the socket *Hello World*: a chat. It is in it's simplest form, just a message sent, no username, time, etc. It basically is the Ratchet example but adapted to WebSockets.

To go further, do not hesitate to rely on documentation ([Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/) and [MDN for JS-side](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications)).

Comment: ah, any chance you could break this down a little for me? ive only recently moved to server side coding and im unfamilier with both of these? Is ratchet a PHP library and Websockets a JS library?